# Extending JOOQ Record

Tags: java, jooq

Does Jooq generator supports extending custom class as provided to generator?

I would like to generate Records that extend custom provided class which will extend TableRecordImpl.

I would like to get into the inheritance chain where UpdatableRecordImpl will extend MyRecord and MyRecord will extend TableRecordImpl?

Answer (score 1):

For most such cases, you can specify a generator strategy:

- [Programmatic](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-generatorstrategy/)
- [Configurative](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-matcherstrategy/)

However, this isn't currently possible for `TableRecordImpl` subtypes. It probably should be possible. I've created a feature request: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/9844.

You can, however, let the records implement your own set of interfaces (see again above links for details), and generate the interface implementation in your records using a [custom code section](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-custom-code/).

Comment: Okay, thank you for you answer and creating feature request. I did make a workaround with java footer generator which generates dsl field on each record to make possible to implement one to many relationships. https://github.com/gpor0/jOOreo/blob/master/src/test/java/com/github/gpor0/jooreo/test/support/records/ReservationRecord.java

Comment: @Gregor: that would produce additional round trips. Why not just join the parent table?

Comment: Having many relationships may produce complex queries (especially outer joins) and large result set, also this way i can achieve lazy load. I will revisit joins.